# Whitespace as a value in .ini file

Tags: python, config, whitespace, ini

I want my `.ini` file to have an option to specify a certain character as a splitter for the parameters which is then handled with Python. That is:

```
[meta]
split_char = " "

[stuff]
field = value_1 value_2
```

How can I specify a whitespace as a split char so it is recognizable? I have tried `" "` or `[ ]` and some other oprions, neither of them works.

As I've been asked, here is the Python scripts to read the `.ini` file:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# I need a nested dictionary, but this is not the point
split_char = config["meta"]["split_char"]
config = {section: dict(config.items(section)) for section in config.sections() if section != "meta"}
for section in config:
    for parameter in config[section]:
        config[section][parameter] = config[section][parameter].split(split_char)
```

If I place a whitespace as it is, Python considers the splitter empty, adding quotes or any other auxiliary signs does not get the things done.

**Update**

The thing is that I would also like to be able to require splitters like ', ', which is a string with a whitespace.

Comment: Please update your question with your code which reads the ini file. Plus show how you know that, for example, `split_char` does not contain what you want it to contain.

Comment: @quamrana done, but I think this is not going to be of much use, the thing is that there is something to be done with the `.ini` file where whitespaces are seemingly ignored

Comment: Concerning the ', ' delimiter. I would avoid diverting too much from how configparser handles strings and follow their approach by calling `str.strip` on each value, even if you have further process them. Simply because users of configparser expect spaces at the exteriors not to matter, so they might have 'bad surprises' when using your code. I would recommend using something like `[s.strip() for s in config[section][parameter].split(split_char)]`, so you apply the same rational to the split values. But in the end it must work for you, that's the most important thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a trickery like:

```
split_char = config["meta"]["split_char"][1:-1]
```

Then the splitter can be placed inside quotes or brackets or whatever:

```
[meta]
split_char = " "
```

The amount of characters to split does not matter as well, it's easy to go with things like `,` .

Answer (score 1):

If you enforce a convention that the value in the ini file will always be:

```
<delim>sep<delim>
```

eg `" "` or `[ ]`, the you can just have:

```py
split_char = config["meta"]["split_char"][1]
```

Comment: Thanks, with this I've come up with a nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are out of luck with the whitespace as separator. ConfigParser [calls str.strip on the value after the delimiter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/configparser.py#L1103).

But this means essentially that whenever you specify a whitespace as `split_car` you will get `''` as value for it. Since `''` is not a valid separator in a string you could simply replace `''` with `' '` when getting `split_char` from `config["meta"]["split_char"]`.

Basically you could adapt the line `split_char = config["meta"]["split_char"]` to:

```
split_char = config["meta"]["split_char"] or ' '
```

and you are good to go!

Comment: I've updated the question. What if I, say, want a splitter like ', ' (a comma with a whitespace)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've suddenly been struck by an idea and have placed it as an answer